# Sequences in totally bounded spaces

Tags: analysis

Let $E$ be totally bounded and $\left\{x_{i}\right\}$ be a sequence in $E$. Prove for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a subsequence $\left\{x_{i_{j}}\right\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\operatorname{diam}\left(\left\{x_{i_{j}}\right\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\right) \leqslant 1 / n$. Then, use this fact and diagonalization to prove that there is subsequence of $\left\{x_{i}\right\}$ that is Cauchy. Conclude that a totally bounded and complete metric space is compact.

**My attempt:**

Let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence in $E$. Since $E$ is totally bounded, for any $\varepsilon >0$, there exist $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in E$ such that the open balls $B(x_i, \varepsilon)$ cover $E$, i.e., $E \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} B(x_i, \varepsilon)$. So, this means that there's a finite subsequence $\{x_{i_j}\}$ of $\{x_i\}$ that the open balls centered in these points with the radius $\varepsilon$ cover $E$. Now, let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{n}$, then $E \subset \cup_{j=1}^n B(x_{i_j}, \frac{1}{n})$ and the only thing that remains to show is that $\operatorname{diam}\left(\left\{x_{i_{j}}\right\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\right) \leqslant 1 / n$. First of all, I don't know if I'm picking the right $\varepsilon$ or not and also I don't know how to show that the diameter is less than $\frac{1}{n}$. I'm thinking that maybe I have to pick $\varepsilon$ to be $\frac{1}{2n}$ so that when I apply the triangle inequality, I get the right amount. Any help is appreciated for this part.

For the second part, I think that after proving the first part, for a sequence, there will be a subsequence contained in $1/2$-radius balls, then this subsequence will have a subsequence contained in $1/3$-radius balls and so on... So, we can write each subsequence in a line so that we can apply the diagonalization and then have a subsequence. But then, to prove that this subsequence is Cauchy, I don't know what to do.

Comment: You are using $x_i$ for a member of a specific sequence in $E$ but in the 1st line of your attempt you also use $x_1,...x_n$ for some (probably different) members of $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first argument is not entirely right. The points that you get to be the center of finite balls of radius $\epsilon$ when you use the total boundedness are not necessarily points in the original sequence. But your intuition is right when you say that you'll probably need $1/2n$ balls. An argument for the first part could be as follows:

Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\epsilon$ be $1/2n$. By total boundedness of $E$, there is a finite collection of $\epsilon$-balls $B(y_1, \epsilon), \ldots, B(y_m, \epsilon)$ that cover $E$. Since $\{x_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite collection, there is a $j \in \{1,\ldots, m\}$ such that an infinite subset of $\{x_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is contained in $B(y_j, \epsilon)$ (it could happen that $\{x_i\}$ is a finite collection, which means that $x_i$ is eventually constant and, in particular, Cauchy).

Let $N_n = \{i \in \mathbb{N} : x_i \in B(y_j, \epsilon)\}$. We know that $N_n$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so $\{x_i\}_{i \in N_n}$ is a subsequence. Now, given $k,l \in N_n$, we have by $\triangle$ inequality
$$
d(x_k,x_l) \leq d(x_k,y_j) + d(y_j,x_l) \leq 1/2n + 1/2n = 1/n. 
$$

Now, for the second part, try to show that you can take $N_1 \supset N_2 \supset \cdots \supset N_n \supset \cdots $ such that for every $n$, $N_n$ is an infinite subset and the subsequence $\{x_i\}_{i \in N_n}$ has diameter less than $1/n$. Take $N = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} N_n$. Notice that $N \subset N_n$ for every $n$. Can $N$ be finite? (what happens if $N$ is finite?) If not, the Cauchy subsequence you're looking for is $\{x_i\}_{i \in N}$.